# I am trying to iterate over multiple lines to extract a specific field while the using the for loop

Tags: python-3.x

thanks for the assistance in advance. So to explain a little bit of what i am trying to do, i want to extract all 'dstprefix' from a list.

```
d = json.dumps(querystring)
response = requests.post(url, data=d).json()

for dstprefix in response: print(dstprefix)
```

my assumption is this would print every line that contains dstprefix without the corresponding data, but it turns out this just returns every line with dstprefix

```
{'bits': 744091635, 'dstprefix': '166.70.0.0/16', 'split1': {'end': '2023-09-27T18:15:00Z', 'start': '2023-09-27T18:14:00.000Z', 'type': 'TIME_RANGE'}}
{'bits': 478661859, 'dstprefix': '67.2.0.0/16', 'split1': {'end': '2023-09-27T18:15:00Z', 'start': '2023-09-27T18:14:00.000Z', 'type': 'TIME_RANGE'}} {'bits': 428178445, 'dstprefix': '65.130.0.0/16', 'split1': {'end': '2023-09-27T18:15:00Z', 'start': '2023-09-27T18:14:00.000Z', 'type': 'TIME_RANGE'}} {'bits': 411131306, 'dstprefix': '97.117.0.0/16', 'split1': {'end': '2023-09-27T18:15:00Z', 'start': '2023-09-27T18:14:00.000Z', 'type': 'TIME_RANGE'}} {'bits': 355640298, 'dstprefix': '174.23.0.0/16', 'split1': {'end': '2023-09-27T18:15:00Z', 'start': '2023-09-27T18:14:00.000Z', 'type': 'TIME_RANGE'}} {'bits': 315676763, 'dstprefix': '66.219.192.0/18', 'split1': {'end': '2023-09-27T18:15:00Z', 'start': '2023-09-27T18:14:00.000Z', 'type': 'TIME_RANGE'}} {'bits': 265467052, 'dstprefix': '83.136.182.0/24', 'split1': {'end': '2023-09-27T18:15:00Z', 'start': '2023-09-27T18:14:00.000Z', 'type': 'TIME_RANGE'}} {'bits': 217480923, 'dstprefix': '75.169.0.0/16', 'split1': {'end': '2023-09-27T18:15:00Z', 'start': '2023-09-27T18:14:00.000Z', 'type': 'TIME_RANGE'}} {'bits': 201852619, 'dstprefix': '69.162.252.0/23', 'split1': {'end': '2023-09-27T18:15:00Z', 'start': '2023-09-27T18:14:00.000Z', 'type': 'TIME_RANGE'}} {'bits': 170697895, 'dstprefix': '38.94.240.0/20', 'split1': {'end': '2023-09-27T18:15:00Z', 'start': '2023-09-27T18:14:00.000Z', 'type': 'TIME_RANGE'}}
```

would the best way to accomplish my use case? would it be to search for a specific expression?

this isnt my first iteration of this code, i initially was doing the following code to extract 'dstprefix' from this json reponse but it was only extracting line by line, and i needed the entire response to be iterated over verus a single line

```
d = json.dumps(querystring)
response = requests.post(url, data=d)
ntop = response.json[0]['dstprefix']
```

so i assumed if i iterated over dstprefix in response it would print dstprefix line by line and instead it print out the entire line including the parameters i wasn't interested in.

Comment: could you add example of `response` ? it seems like your response is a list object containing JSON objects and when you iterate over this list, you are printing each  JSON object.

Comment: `for dstprefix in response: print(dstprefix["dstprefix"])` is what would work I assume.

Comment: @BijayRegmi   >>> print(response)
[{'bits': 744091635, 'dstprefix': '166.70.0.0/16', 'split1': {'end': '2023-09-27T18:15:00Z', 'start': '2023-09-27T18:14:00.000Z', 'type': 'TIME_RANGE'}}, {'bits': 478661859, 'dstprefix': '67.2.0.0/16', 'split1': {'end': '2023-09-27T18:15:00Z', 'start': '2023-09-27T18:14:00.000Z', 'type': 'TIME_RANGE'}}, {'bits': 428178445, 'dstprefix': '65.130.0.0/16', 'split1': {'end': '2023-09-27T18:15:00Z', 'start': '2023-09-27T18:14:00.000Z', 'type': 'TIME_RANGE'}},

Comment: to get all `dstprefix` as list, you can do `dst_prefixes = [item["dstprefix"] for item in response]` and if you just want to print, see code in my second comment